# 3D plot in R error

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I have been trying to plot a 3d plot of my data but I cannot figure out how to overcome some errors. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
>head(d1) #produced through the melt function as seen below
     Date variable     value
1 2007 Q2    0.890 1.1358560
2 2007 Q3    0.890 1.1560433
3 2007 Q4    0.890 0.3747925
4 2008 Q1    0.890 0.3866533
5 2008 Q2    0.890 0.3872620
6 2008 Q3    0.890 0.3844887
```

I have successfully managed to plot a heatmap using this:

```
d1<-melt(mydata,id.vars = "Date")
P1 <- ggplot(data=d1, aes(x=Date, y=variable, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  ggtitle("My heatmap") +scale_fill_gradientn(colors=colorRampPalette(c("lightgray","royalblue","seagreen","orange","red","brown"))(500),name="Variable") +
  labs(x = "Quarter",y="Alpha") +
  theme_bw()
ggplotly(P1)
*Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type yearqtr. Defaulting to continuous.*
```

[image]

However, I want to create a 3d plot.

```
open3d()
rgl.surface(x=d1$variable, y=d1$Date, 
            coords=c(1,3,2),z=d1$value, 
            color=colorzjet[ findInterval(d1$value, seq(min(d1$value), max(d1$value), length=100))] )
axes3d()
Error in rgl.surface(x = d1$variable, y = d1$Date, coords = c(1, 3, 2),  : 
'y' length != 'x' rows * 'z' cols


plot_ly(x=d1$Date,y=d1$variable,z=d1$value,type="surface",colors=colors)
Error: `z` must be a numeric matrix
I have tried to use as.matrix(apply(d1,2,as.numeric)), but this returns NAs to the date argument.
```

Could it be the nature of the Quarterly dates that messes up the graph? (because even the heat map doesn't show the dates as Quarterly. Any tips?

`dput(d1)` output here: [dput(d1) output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzacyc33o0qlkxt/dput_output.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Could you post the output of `dput(d1)`.

Comment: Done. But I removed a few lines so that I am allowed to post the changes due to character limits in the question)

Comment: Indeed, you need a matrix, corresponding to rows and columns.

Comment: Never use rgl.* functions if you have an alternative.  Use `surface3d()` instead.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent but even when i convert the `d1` to a matrix it doesn't work. Or you mean something else?

Comment: @user2554330 `surface3d(d1$Date,d1$variable,d1$value)
Error in rgl.surface(x = c(2007.25, 2007.5, 2007.75, 2008, 2008.25, 2008.5,  : 
  'y' length != 'x' rows * 'z' cols` . :/ :/

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear:   Stéphane Laurent got the main problem (you need numeric matrices, not dataframe columns); but `rgl.surface` will cause other problems.  `surface3d` will fix those.

Comment: Your `dput(d1)` looks corrupted:  the columns are not all the same length.

Comment: @user2554330 Yes! The reason is that I had to delete some of the rows, because of character restrictions (It wasn't letting post the whole thing).

Comment: Then you should shrink your example to something that is valid if you want help.  We can't run code on garbage data.

Comment: @user2554330 uploaded the `dput` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you uploaded is a CSV file, not `dput` output.  But you can read it and plot it like this:

```
d1csv <- read.csv("dput_output.csv")
year <- as.numeric(sub(" .*", "", d1csv$Date))
quarter <- as.numeric(sub(".*Q", "", d1csv$Date))

Date <- matrix(year + (quarter - 1)/4, 55)
variable <- matrix(d1csv$variable, 55)
value <- matrix(d1csv$value, 55)

persp3d(Date, variable, value, col = "red")
```

This gives the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you! One minor last thing...Is it possible to make it like a rainbow? What I mean; is that the high values are red and the lower the values are blue, like the heatmap.